# StringBuilder not being initialized to the length value given

Tags: java, constructor, stringbuilder

I am trying to create a StringBuilder object with a given length, but every time I try to do so, the length of the StringBuilder object is printed as 0. Anyone know why?

```
String s = "i";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length()+1);
System.out.println(sb.length());
```

In the above code, the length of the StringBuilder object should be 2 (1 from the length of "i" + 1), but when I print the StringBuilder's length in Eclipse, I get 0. I changed the length to 17 and 100, but I still got 0 as `sb`'s length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not setting its length in that constructor, you're setting its [*capacity*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)).
Its length is the number of `chars` actually *in* it and you haven't yet appended any characters to it.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are setting the maximum capacity of the StringBuilder. The length represents the actual size of the constructed string. Let me demonstrate:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(5);
System.out.println("Length after initialization with capacity: " + sb.length());
sb.append("abcd");
System.out.println("Length after appending: " + sb.length());
```

Output:

```
Length after initialization with capacity: 0
Length after appending: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [official documentation for the `StringBuilder(int capacity)` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder(int)),

> Constructs a string builder with no characters in it and an initial capacity specified by the capacity argument.

There are no characters in the `StringBuilder` instance yet. It’s just setting an initial capacity of the resource it uses to store the data based on the `int` argument you passed in.